# [ubuntu 17.04][pdflatex] 'Font umvs at 600 not found'

Tags: pdftex

I was about to edit my CV that I created a year ago with pdflatex. However my computer setup has changed since then. I don't exactly understand why I cannot compile it with my current setup.

I tried using 'pdflatex filename.tex' in the terminal, but it is not working. The missfont.log says:

```
mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 umvs
```

I am not sure what information I should otherwise add but these are the includes I am using in my .tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
```

Edit1:

I tried:

```
sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra
```

downloading went fine but at the end I get this message:

> Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done. 
>   Running updmap-sys. This may take some time...
>   updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in /tmp/updmap.vZar5H3y 
>   Please include this file if you report a bug.
>
> Sometimes, not accepting conffile updates in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
>   causes updmap-sys to fail.  Please check for files with extension
>   .dpkg-dist or .ucf-dist in this directory
>
> dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):  subprocess
>   installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 Errors
>   were encountered while processing:  tex-common E: Sub-process
>   /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

This will install the missing packages and other files necessary to run TeXLive.

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating to your `/miktex/bin` directory and running the following.

```
initexmf --mkmaps
initexmf --update-fndb
```

Reference: https://www.dev-eth0.de/2016/11/13/latex_miktex-makepk-pk-font-umvs-could-not-be-created/